# Which full node implementation(s) supports SegWit2x?

Tags: full-node, segwit2x

I'm running a full node, because I want to support the Bitcoin network, and because I'm interested in the backend mechanisms in Bitcoin.

Now, SegWit2x is approaching. I believe it's important for Bitcoin to increase the block size, so I would like to somehow support the doubling of the block size. Can I somehow support SegWit2x through my choice of full node software? If I can choose between Bitcoin Core, Bitcoin ABC, Bitcoin XT, and Bitcoin Classic: Are there any feature differences that would make those more or less supportive of the block size doubling?

Comment: As it stands, asking which one is "best" is primarily opinion based, it would be better to reword your question to ask which software is available to run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I can choose between Bitcoin Core, Bitcoin ABC, Bitcoin XT, and Bitcoin Classic

None of these software support Segwit2x. Currently your only choice of Full node software for Segwit2x is [btc1](https://github.com/btc1/bitcoin).

Comment: Thanks! A follow-up question: Am I correct in thinking that plain Bitcoin Core currently does not support SegWit2x?

Comment: Yes, Bitcoin Core does not support segwit2x.

Comment: But it says here that BTC1, Bitcoin Unlimited & Bitcoin Classic are compatible.... https://segwit2x.github.io/segwit2x-announce.html

Comment: And this is alert on the main unlimited site pointing to this statement : https://medium.com/@peter_r/bitcoin-network-upgrade-at-block-494-784-f5ca19829529 - where it says for example that: "What this means for Bitcoin Unlimited node operators: [...] No action is required from Bitcoin Unlimited node operators."

Answer (score 1):

**Bitcoin Core** will not follow the B2x blockchain tip, as B2x requires a block exceeding Bitcoin's blockweight limit at fork height which Bitcoin Core will reject as invalid.

**BTC1** is the reference implementation of the New York Agreement and thus will follow the B2x blockchain.

**Bitcoin Unlimited** is an implementation of the Bitcoin protocol that doesn't enforce the current blockweight limit and thus will follow the B2x blockchain.

**BitcoinABC** is an implementations of the Bitcoin Cash protocol and will thusly not follow the B2x chain.

I've not kept up to date on **Bitcoin XT** and **Bitcoin Classic**. It seems that today the former is an implementation of the Bitcoin Cash protocol and the latter may be following Bitcoin but allowing a higher blockweight.